# Unable to bind dynamically created content to global jQuery compiled via webpack and Laravel Mix

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, webpack

I have a fresh Laravel 5.4 project that incorporates the new [Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix) wrapper around Webpack and am unable to bind dynamically created content with the global jQuery object.

I'm able to successfully mix/compile my Laravel spark project resources where jQuery is globally available in an app.js file where jQuery is successfully injected via mix/webpack as follows:

window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

As long as my jQuery code is compiled via Mix/webpack, all of my jQuery code works as expected.  The problem I'm having is some of my jQuery modules are called on an ajax success and are not dynamically binding to the global jQuery object. For example:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {symbol: getsymbol},
        url: '../../getCharts',
        success: function (data) {
           //$( "#dialog" ).text('testing');       
           $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                show: {
                    effect: "blind",
                    duration: 1000
                },
                hide: {
                    effect: "explode",
                    duration: 1000
                }
            });

            $( "#opener" ).on( "click", function() {
                $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
            });
        }
    });
```

Since it's challenging to replicate this in a fiddle, here are the steps I followed:

1. use a spark/laravel 5.4 install (or where app.js includes jQuery as
   global)
2. npm install --save jquery-ui-bundle
3. webpack .combine and .js as appropriate ('node_modules/jquery-ui-bundle/jquery-ui.xx')
4. verify that jqueryui is compiled into supporting css/js files (mine is ux-full.css/js)
5. assemble page resources adding app.js followed by ux-full.js
6. place a button (#opener) and div (#dialog) on the page
7. on page, make an ajax call to a controller where on success set #dialog.text('testing');

so far, so good, at least we know that jQuery is being called successfully. Now it's time to dynamically call jQueryUI.

8. now that we know that jquery/ajax works, replace the on success test with a simple jqueryui component like the code snippet above.

I get an error message `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function` which would indicate to me that this dynamically created component is not binding to the global jQuery object.

I'm 99% sure this problem is simply user error, I've just never had this problem before and I'm very new to webpack.

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, since I'm using a Laravel installation with Spark, the webpack/bootstrap process is slightly different than what is documented or posted here to SO. With the Spark webpack config, I had to add the require to app.js, not bootstrap.js as follows

```
require('spark-bootstrap');

require('./components/bootstrap');


require('../../../node_modules/jquery-ui-bundle/jquery-ui.min.js');


var app = new Vue({
    mixins: [require('spark')]
});
```

Now jqueryui is available globally in app.js.